# UWP Azure AD authentication for the Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Trying to develop a UWP prototype application that accesses basic information about other people who work for my company using the Microsoft Graph API.

To authenticate I am using the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` NuGet package, aka `MSAL` to get an OAuth token.

I have created a native `Converged application` in the new [App Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). I logged into the portal using my work email address and there is a note on the app when I view it that says "This application will be registered in the Azure Active Directory instance used to manage your connel.hooley@modalitysystems.com account.". I cannot see this application registered against my work's Azure AD instance in the Azure Portal.

I am using its `ClientID` in my app. It has the following redirects t:

- `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`
- `e7b70686-d176-4a1c-aae6-151221fafe0e://auth`

Whenever I try and login I enter my work email address and the popup redirects to my work's log in page. Once I type in my password I am redirected to a blank page with the following error message:

> We can't connect to the service you need right now. Check your network connection or try this again later.

I can successfully log in to the [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with my work email address and then access the Graph API there to access the information I need.

I've tried running Fiddler to find out where the popup is trying to go but Fiddler running stops it from working at all.

I am using the [active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2) demo app from Microsoft to try and get the auth working:

Below is the method that logs a user in:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Call AcquireTokenAsync - to acquire a token requiring user to sign-in
/// </summary>
private async void CallGraphButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
    ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
    TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
    {
        // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

        try
        {
            authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
        }
        catch (MsalException msalex)
        {
            ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
        return;
    }

    if (authResult != null)
    {
        ResultText.Text = await GetHttpContentWithToken(graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken);
        DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);
        this.SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

The `App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes)` line is the one that brings up the popup.

Below is the line that constructs `App.PublicClientApp`:

```cs
public static PublicClientApplication PublicClientApp { get; } = new PublicClientApplication(ClientId);
```

Is there anything else I need to do to get the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` to work for with my company's AD? Or is there anything I can do to investigate what's missing?

Comment: Could you add the code you're using and the details from your app's registration?

Comment: I'm using the following demo app just to try and get the auth working:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2

What details from the app's registration would you like? I've added the redirects to the question.

Comment: Umm, shouldn't you use the v2 apps portal to define the app if you want to use v2 endpoints (MSAL)? You can find it at apps.dev.microsoft.com

Comment: I've tried creating the app in both the Azure Portal and the new app portal. Both give me the same error message. When I create the application in the new portal, it does not show up in the Azure Portal against the AD instance in the "app registrations" page, is this normal?

Comment: I've updated the question to cover the converged app scenario.

Comment: With v2, you won't see anything in your tenant until it has been authorized so that is normal. What is the value of scopes? It would also help too see how `App.PublicClientApp` is being constructed.

Comment: You can see the ClientApp being constructed here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2/blob/master/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2/App.xaml.cs

I'll also add this to the question.

Comment: Probably not your issue, but why do you have the 2 other redirect URIs in your configuration above?  urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob should be sufficient.  In fact the 2nd one is just plain wrong, since that's anendpoint that Microsoft (and not your app) owns.

Comment: I created the app as a "Converged application" using the new portal. It gives you the first two redirects by default. It also creates the final GUID randomly for each app you create. Converged apps allow users to sign in with their Microsoft accounts, plus on prem AD accounts, so I guess it makes sense that they're both there.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

1. Make sure to enable the following settings on your app:

   - Enterprise Authentication
   - Private Networks (Client & Server)
   - Shared User Certificates
2. Find your redirect URL as the following:

   - Discover the callback URI for your app by adding the following like and setting a breakpoint on:

```
var redirectURI = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
```

- Run the app, and copy the value of redirectUri when the breakpoint is hit. The value should look something similar to the following:

  *ms-app://s-1-15-2-1352796503-54529114-405753024-3540103335-3203256200-511895534-1429095407/*

  3. Add a RedirectUri with the value returned in the Application Registration Portal

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but how can I find Application Registration Portal?